# how does youtube convert videos to mp4/flv when uploading the video

Tags: php, upload, video-streaming, jwplayer, swfupload

Hi i'm making a site in wordpress using a theme called [wptube2](http://www.bdtubez.com/) and it has all the Youtube look and stuff but what I need is that when I upload some video it just uploads I want it to be able to change it format to like MP4 and be published in my own player like jwplayer but I don't know where to start any suggestions would be greatly appreciated I just want to upload any video format and it should automatically be converted it to MP4 and published with jwplayer
[here](http://prntscr.com/ozgp9) is a screen shot where i publish my videos from!

Answer (score 1):

I used [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to do all my conversions.

You could make your uploaded video files all go to one central folder.  Have a batch file that runs ffmpeg on those files and then move it to the another folder once it is processed.

You could upload your file in whatever format, give it a fake .mp4 file name and just have a message that says "file being processed" in the meantime.

File conversion takes time, and a lot of processing power, be sure to try it locally before even considering making your server do all the work.

Comment: Probably ffmpeg is indeed the right tool for the job. If the complexity of using ffmpeg, or the processing power required is a problem, I suggest looking into cloud-based transcoding services.

Comment: Thank You Very Much for this suggestion but do i need vps to install ffmpeg ?

Comment: Yes you will need to install it to use it. You can try it out on your home computer, I believe there are ports available for all OS's.